# The conditional check 'user_sdf_exist.rc == 0' failed

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook and it fails only on one server and rest all server it is not giving any error

```
---
- hosts: user_host
  tasks:
  - name: check sdf user exists
    command: grep -Fq "sdf" /etc/passwd
    register: user_sdf_exist
    ignore_errors: True
    changed_when: False

 - name: check authorized_keys file exits
    stat: path=/home/sdf/.ssh/authorized_keys
    register: authorized_keys_file
    when: user_sdf_exist.rc == 0
```

Follwoing is the error that I received

```
fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'user_sdf_exist.rc == 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (user_sdf_exist.rc == 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/sdf/bin/configs/ansible/playbooks/roles/ansible_pub_key_for_sdf/tasks/main.yml': line 8, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: check authorized_keys file exits\n  ^ here\n"}
```

But when running the playbook only for this one host playbook passes and returns user_sdf_exist.rc == 0. We have a cron that will run this playbook for every one hour on all the hosts and during this time playbook fails only on this one host.

Output

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false, 
        "cmd": [
            "grep", 
            "-Fq", 
            "sdf", 
            "/etc/passwd"
        ], 
        "delta": "0:00:00.175056", 
        "end": "2019-12-11 12:58:50.601619", 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2019-12-11 12:58:50.426563", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stdout": "", 
        "stdout_lines": [], 
        "warnings": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `when: user_sdf_exist.rc == 0`
you need to use `when: user_sdf_exist is succeeded`

Comment: thanks. this works.,. but there is another error. `"The conditional check 'authorized_keys_file.stat.exists == False' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (authorized_keys_file.stat.exists == False): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'`...Can we use  `when: authorized_keys_file.stat.exists is failed` instead of `when: authorized_keys_file.stat.exists == False`

Comment: please mark the answer as solution if it worked. For your other question, it can be `when: authorized_keys_file == false`, but please paste the output of register variable `authorized_keys_file` in your question to check further.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. i am unable to paste the complete output for register varibale